# Main tag in Main tag

Tags: html

I am trying to code a website in html and am looking for ways to structure my code (without spams of divs)

And I was wondering, are you able to have a <main> tag inside another <main> tag? **If so, it is good pratice?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may only have one `<main>` tag per page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the W3C specification of `<main>`:

> The main element represents the dominant contents of the document.
>
> A document must not have more than one main element that does not have the hidden attribute specified.
>
> A hierarchically correct main element is one whose ancestor elements are limited to html, body, div, form without an accessible name, and autonomous custom elements. Each main element must be a hierarchically correct main element.

As per [The main element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-main-element) (HTML.Spec)

See also a more simplified version of the above:

> One important facet of  is that it can only be used once per page.

As per [The main element](http://html5doctor.com/the-main-element/)  (HTML5 Doctor)

---

If you're still unclear why this matters, please read more on [Semantic / Non-Semantic Elements in HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp):

> Examples of non-semantic elements: `<div>` and `<span>` - Tells nothing about its content.
>
> Examples of semantic elements: `<form>`, `<table>`, and `<article>` - Clearly defines its content.

---

**In answer to your question:**

- You cannot nest `<main>` elements, as per the W3C specifications and also have valid HTML
- You may only have one `<main>` tag per page

Does that answer your question?